# Flutter: Change background color of Container conditionally on button press

Tags: flutter, dart

**Hi there,**
I'm working on a drag & drop game in Flutter.
What works so far is that each Draggable can be dropped on every DragTarget & text shows up on the DragTarget (if the latter is still "empty") as desired.

To make it visible whether the answer was correct or wrong, I want to change the color of the DragTarget-Container on button press. The button shows up when there are no more elements left.

- So far, I store the information like this: `onAccept`: `if (shuffledElements[j]["atomicNumber"] == tmpElement.atomicNumber)`.

I thought about giving the `tmpElement` the information (`tmpElement.answer = "correct"; tmpElement.answer = "wrong";`), accessing it here:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    if (tmpElement.answer == 'correct') {
      tileColor = Colors.green;
    } else {
      tileColor = Colors.red;
    }
    checked = true;
  });
}
```

and triggering it for the color property like so:`checked ? tileColor : Colors.white38`.
But obviously, this statement was triggered upon build already and found to be false, so it shows the white38 color.

How can I re-trigger this (or find another solution to make this work)?

Please see the full code below:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable & DragTarget',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class ElementModel {
  ElementModel({
    this.key,
    this.atomicNumber,
    this.element,
    this.symbol,
    this.group,
    this.period,
    this.droppedKey,
    this.accepting,
    this.successfulDrop,
    this.correctDrop,
    this.answer,
  });
  String key;
  int atomicNumber;
  String element;
  String symbol;
  int group;
  int period;
  String droppedKey = '';
  bool accepting = false;
  bool successfulDrop = false;
  bool correctDrop = false;
  String answer = '';
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List elementData = [
    {
      "key": "1x1",
      "atomicNumber": 1,
      "element": "Wasserstoff",
      "symbol": "H",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "1x2",
      "atomicNumber": 3,
      "element": "Lithium",
      "symbol": "Li",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "1x3",
      "atomicNumber": 11,
      "element": "Natrium",
      "symbol": "Na",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "1x4",
      "atomicNumber": 19,
      "element": "Kalium",
      "symbol": "K",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 4
    }
  ];

  int j = 0;
  List<Widget> _elements;
  List shuffledElements;
  int tableRows = 4;
  int tableCols = 1;
  String key;
  int index;
  var tmpElement;
  bool accepting = false;
  bool successfulDrop = false;
  bool correctDrop = false;

  var droppedItem;
  int indexDropped;

  List droppedItems = [];
  int droppedItemIndex;
  List shuffledElementsCopy;
  List elementDataCopy;

  bool showCheckButton = false;
  Color tileColor;
  bool checked = false;

  List shuffleElements() {
    var random = Random();
    shuffledElements = List.from(elementData);
    for (var i = shuffledElements.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var n = random.nextInt(i + 1);
      var temp = shuffledElements[i];
      shuffledElements[i] = shuffledElements[n];
      shuffledElements[n] = temp;
    }
    return shuffledElements;
  }

  void nextElement() {
    setState(() {
      if (j < shuffledElements.length - 1) {
        j++;
      } else {
        showCheckButton = true;
      }
    });
  }

  List<Widget> getElements() {
    if (_elements != null) {
      return _elements;
    }

    elementDataCopy = elementData
        .map((element) => ElementModel(
              key: element['key'],
              atomicNumber: element['atomicNumber'],
              element: element['element'],
              symbol: element['symbol'],
              group: element['group'],
              period: element['period'],
              accepting: element['accepting'],
              successfulDrop: element['successfulDrop'],
              correctDrop: element['correctDrop'],
              droppedKey: element['droppedKey'],
            ))
        .toList();
    _elements = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < tableCols; c++) {
      for (var r = 0; r < tableRows; r++) {
        key = '${c + 1}x${r + 1}';
        index = elementDataCopy.indexWhere((e) => e.key.contains(key));

        if (!index.isNegative) {
          tmpElement = elementDataCopy[index];
          _elements.add(elementDragTarget(tmpElement));
        } else {}
      }
    }
    return _elements;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    shuffleElements();
    shuffledElementsCopy = List.from(shuffledElements);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Drag and Drop')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white38,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: tableRows,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: getElements(),
            ),
          ),
          showCheckButton
              ? ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('check'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // some function to perform when pressed to change color of dragtarget

                    setState(() {
                      if (tmpElement.answer == 'correct') {
                        tileColor = Colors.green;
                      } else {
                        tileColor = Colors.red;
                      }
                      checked = true;
                    });
                  },
                )
              : Draggable(
                  data: shuffledElements[j],
                  child: DraggableElementTile(
                    shuffledElements: shuffledElements,
                    j: j,
                  ),
                  feedback: DraggableElementTile(
                    shuffledElements: shuffledElements,
                    j: j,
                  ),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 80,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//problem: if I hover over tiles that already show data
// it changes to last data
  Widget elementDragTarget(tmpElement) {
    return DragTarget(
      onWillAccept: (data) {
        if (tmpElement.successfulDrop == true) {
          tmpElement.accepting = false;
          return false;
        } else {
          setState(() {
            tmpElement.accepting = true;
          });
          return true;
        }
      },
      onAccept: (data) {
        setState(() {
          tmpElement.successfulDrop = true;

          if (shuffledElements[j]["atomicNumber"] == tmpElement.atomicNumber) {
            tmpElement.correctDrop = true;
            tmpElement.accepting = false;

            tmpElement.answer = "correct";
          } else {
            tmpElement.correctDrop = false;
            tmpElement.accepting = false;

            tmpElement.answer = "wrong";
          }
          tmpElement.droppedKey = shuffledElements[j]['key'] + 'dropped';
          shuffledElementsCopy[j]['droppedKey'] = tmpElement.droppedKey;
          droppedItems.add(shuffledElements[j]);
          droppedItemIndex = droppedItems.indexWhere(
              (e) => e['droppedKey'] == shuffledElements[j]['key'] + 'dropped');
          droppedItem = droppedItems[droppedItemIndex];

          tmpElement.symbol = droppedItem['symbol'];
          tmpElement.atomicNumber = droppedItem['atomicNumber'];
          tmpElement.element = droppedItem['element'];
          tmpElement.group = droppedItem['group'];
          tmpElement.period = droppedItem['period'];
        });

        nextElement();
      },
      onLeave: (data) {
        setState(() {
          tmpElement.accepting = false;
        });
        return false;
      },
      builder: (context, acceptedData, rejectedData) {
        return buildElementTileInGrid(tmpElement);
      },
    );
  }

  //show in grid onAccept
  Container buildElementTileInGrid(tmpElement) {
    accepting = tmpElement.accepting;
    successfulDrop = tmpElement.successfulDrop;
    correctDrop = tmpElement.correctDrop;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 4,
          color: accepting == true ? Colors.teal : Colors.transparent,
        ),
        color: checked
            ? tileColor
            : Colors.white38, //TODO: Change this color conditionally on check
      ),
      child: successfulDrop == true
          ? Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(tmpElement.atomicNumber.toString()),
                Text(tmpElement.symbol),
              ],
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}

//draggable
class DraggableElementTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableElementTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.shuffledElements,
    @required this.j,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List shuffledElements;
  final int j;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.teal,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      height: 100,
      width: 80,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text(
            shuffledElements[j]['symbol'],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          Text(
            shuffledElements[j]['element'],
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer with a solution:

Here's a solution using GetX. Perhaps someone else can chime in with a more elegant way but this works. Here's the new ColorController class.

```
class ColorController extends GetxController {
  Color color1 = Colors.white38;
  Color color2 = Colors.white38;
  Color color3 = Colors.white38;
  Color color4 = Colors.white38;

  List<Color> colorList = [];
  List<bool> answerList = [];
 
  @override
  onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    colorList = [
      color1,
      color2,
      color3,
      color4
    ]; // initializing the list in onInit because it can't be accessed in initalizer
  }

  void updateColors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++) {
      if (answerList[i]) {
        colorList[i] = Colors.green;
      } else {
        colorList[i] = Colors.red;
      }
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

And the rest of the code

```
void main() {
  Get.put(ColorController()); // initalizing ColorController on app start
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable & DragTarget',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class ElementModel {
  ElementModel({
    this.key,
    this.atomicNumber,
    this.element,
    this.symbol,
    this.group,
    this.period,
    this.droppedKey,
    this.accepting,
    this.successfulDrop,
    this.correctDrop,
    this.answer,
  });
  String key;
  int atomicNumber;
  String element;
  String symbol;
  int group;
  int period;
  String droppedKey = '';
  bool accepting = false;
  bool successfulDrop = false;
  bool correctDrop = false;
  String answer = '';
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List elementData = [
    {
      "key": "1x1",
      "atomicNumber": 1,
      "element": "Wasserstoff",
      "symbol": "H",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "1x2",
      "atomicNumber": 3,
      "element": "Lithium",
      "symbol": "Li",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "1x3",
      "atomicNumber": 11,
      "element": "Natrium",
      "symbol": "Na",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 3
    },
    {
      "key": "1x4",
      "atomicNumber": 19,
      "element": "Kalium",
      "symbol": "K",
      "group": 1,
      "period": 4
    }
  ];

  int j = 0;
  List<Widget> _elements;
  List shuffledElements;
  int tableRows = 4;
  int tableCols = 1;
  String key;
  int index;
  var tmpElement;
  bool accepting = false;
  bool successfulDrop = false;
  bool correctDrop = false;

  var droppedItem;
  int indexDropped;

  List droppedItems = [];
  int droppedItemIndex;
  List shuffledElementsCopy;
  List elementDataCopy;

  bool showCheckButton = false;
  Color tileColor;
  bool checked = false;

  List shuffleElements() {
    var random = Random();
    shuffledElements = List.from(elementData);
    for (var i = shuffledElements.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var n = random.nextInt(i + 1);
      var temp = shuffledElements[i];
      shuffledElements[i] = shuffledElements[n];
      shuffledElements[n] = temp;
    }
    return shuffledElements;
  }

  void nextElement() {
    setState(() {
      if (j < shuffledElements.length - 1) {
        j++;
      } else {
        showCheckButton = true;
      }
    });
  }

  List<Widget> getElements() {
    if (_elements != null) {
      return _elements;
    }

    elementDataCopy = elementData
        .map((element) => ElementModel(
              key: element['key'],
              atomicNumber: element['atomicNumber'],
              element: element['element'],
              symbol: element['symbol'],
              group: element['group'],
              period: element['period'],
              accepting: element['accepting'],
              successfulDrop: element['successfulDrop'],
              correctDrop: element['correctDrop'],
              droppedKey: element['droppedKey'],
            ))
        .toList();
    _elements = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < tableCols; c++) {
      for (var r = 0; r < tableRows; r++) {
        key = '${c + 1}x${r + 1}';
        index = elementDataCopy.indexWhere((e) => e.key.contains(key));

        if (!index.isNegative) {
          tmpElement = elementDataCopy[index];
          _elements.add(elementDragTarget(tmpElement,
              r)); // using this index r to pull colors from Color list and passing it all the way down to buildElementTileInGrid
        } else {}
      }
    }
    return _elements;
  }

  final colorController =
      Get.find<ColorController>(); // finding initialized ColorController

  @override
  void initState() {
    shuffleElements();
    shuffledElementsCopy = List.from(shuffledElements);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Drag and Drop')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white38,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: tableRows,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: getElements(),
            ),
          ),
          showCheckButton
              ? ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('check'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // some function to perform when pressed to change color of dragtarget
                    colorController
                        .updateColors(); // new function from ColorController class
                    setState(() {
                      // if (tmpElement.answer == 'correct') {
                      //   tileColor = Colors.green;
                      // } else {
                      //   tileColor = Colors.red;
                      // }
                      checked = true;
                    });
                  },
                )
              : Draggable(
                  data: shuffledElements[j],
                  child: DraggableElementTile(
                    shuffledElements: shuffledElements,
                    j: j,
                  ),
                  feedback: DraggableElementTile(
                    shuffledElements: shuffledElements,
                    j: j,
                  ),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 80,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//problem: if I hover over tiles that already show data
// it changes to last data
  Widget elementDragTarget(tmpElement, int i) {
    return DragTarget(
      onWillAccept: (data) {
        if (tmpElement.successfulDrop == true) {
          tmpElement.accepting = false;
          return false;
        } else {
          setState(() {
            tmpElement.accepting = true;
          });
          return true;
        }
      },
      onAccept: (data) {
        setState(() {
          tmpElement.successfulDrop = true;

          if (shuffledElements[j]["atomicNumber"] == tmpElement.atomicNumber) {
            tmpElement.correctDrop = true;
            tmpElement.accepting = false;

            tmpElement.answer = "correct";
            colorController.answerList
                .add(true); // adding correct bool to the answer list
            debugPrint(('correct'));
          } else {
            tmpElement.correctDrop = false;
            tmpElement.accepting = false;

            tmpElement.answer = "wrong";
            colorController.answerList
                .add(false); // adding incorrect bool to the answer list
            debugPrint(('wrong'));
          }
          tmpElement.droppedKey = shuffledElements[j]['key'] + 'dropped';
          shuffledElementsCopy[j]['droppedKey'] = tmpElement.droppedKey;
          droppedItems.add(shuffledElements[j]);
          droppedItemIndex = droppedItems.indexWhere(
              (e) => e['droppedKey'] == shuffledElements[j]['key'] + 'dropped');
          droppedItem = droppedItems[droppedItemIndex];

          tmpElement.symbol = droppedItem['symbol'];
          tmpElement.atomicNumber = droppedItem['atomicNumber'];
          tmpElement.element = droppedItem['element'];
          tmpElement.group = droppedItem['group'];
          tmpElement.period = droppedItem['period'];
        });

        nextElement();
      },
      onLeave: (data) {
        setState(() {
          tmpElement.accepting = false;
        });
        return false;
      },
      builder: (context, acceptedData, rejectedData) {
        return buildElementTileInGrid(tmpElement, i);
      },
    );
  }

  //show in grid onAccept
  Widget buildElementTileInGrid(tmpElement, int i) {
    accepting = tmpElement.accepting;
    successfulDrop = tmpElement.successfulDrop;
    correctDrop = tmpElement.correctDrop;

    return GetBuilder<ColorController>(builder: (_) {
      // GetBuilder is the widget that updates the color
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 4,
            color: accepting == true ? Colors.teal : Colors.transparent,
          ),
          color: colorController
              .colorList[i], // pulling color from GetXController color list
        ),
        child: successfulDrop == true
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text(tmpElement.atomicNumber.toString()),
                  Text(tmpElement.symbol),
                ],
              )
            : Container(),
      );
    });
  }
}

//draggable
class DraggableElementTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableElementTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.shuffledElements,
    @required this.j,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List shuffledElements;
  final int j;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.teal,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      height: 100,
      width: 80,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text(
            shuffledElements[j]['symbol'],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          Text(
            shuffledElements[j]['element'],
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Old answer:

It'd be easier just to initialize tileColor to `Colors.white38` as use that variable as your container color without the ternary operator. Then use setState to change the color of tileColor based on condition in the onPressed.

Comment: Thank you. Initializing the tileColor totally makes sense. However, can you please elaborate a bit more on how to write the setState, so it actually changes the tileColor of each individual `tmpElement` on screen?

Comment: See updated answer. You'll have to import the GetX package.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.